# numpy vectorize a parallel update

Tags: python, numpy

I want to implement a one-dimensional cellular automaton with the following simple rules:

1. If cell is **1** and neighbor cell is **0**, move (to the right)
2. if cell is **1** and neighbor cell is **1**,  don't move
3. All cells update at the same time according to their state.
4. We have **closed boundary conditions**. That means the neighbor of the last cell is the first cell.

For example:

`0 1 1 0 1`

After update:

`1 1 0 1 0`

My solution is

```
def update(cells):
    neighbors = np.roll(cells,-1)
    dim = len(cells)
    tmp_cells = np.zeros(dim)
    for i,j in  enumerate(cells):
        if j and not neighbors[i]:
            tmp_cells[i], tmp_cells[(i+1)%dim] = 0, 1
        elif j:
            tmp_cells[i] = 1
    return tmp_cells
```

That works fine, but the solution do not exploit all the possibilities of `np.arrays` and reduces to a simple `list`-algorithm.

I thought I could find a neat logic between `cells` and `neighbors`, but apparently I have to go sleep now.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 5):

To get the value for a cell without looping, you need to know its neighbors on *both* sides. You need the left because if you're a `0` your new value depends on your left neighbor's, while if you're a `1` your new value depends on your right neighbor.

You can exhaustively write all the 3-cell combinations, right? In other words:

```
000 -> 0
001 -> 0
010 -> 0 # move to the right
011 -> 1 # stay put
100 -> 1 # left neighbor has moved
101 -> 1 # left neighbor has moved
110 -> 0 # move to the right
111 -> 1 # stay put
```

You can turn that table into a boolean function pretty easily. We could simplify it, but let's just be stupid to start with: `-x & y & z | x & -y & -z | x & -y & z | x & y & z`.

And that's it:

```
left = np.roll(cells, -1)
right = np.roll(cells, 1)
return (np.logical_not(left) & cells & right | # ...)
```

Now of course you'll want to simplify the boolean equation,* but this should get you started.

<sub>* Or maybe step back and rethink the rules. If you're a `0`, your new value is always copied from your left neighbor; if you're a `1`, it's always copied from your right neighbor. You can write that with a combination of boolean operators, but it might be even simpler with masked assignment: `result[cells] = left[cells]; result[notcells] = right[notcells]`.</sub>

Comment: the variation after stepping back is the simplest. However, the `1` get the value of its right, not the negation of its right.

Comment: @Tengis: Thanks! (And to myself: duh…) Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

roll as suggested by abarnert would work, but creates two copies, which isn't ideal from a performance perspective.

For the best performance, it would be better to use views. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np

cells = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
cells = np.concatenate([[0],cells, [0]])    #add padding cells
def boundary(cells):
    """enforce boundary conditions"""
    cells[0] = cells[-2]
    cells[-1] = cells[1]
    return cells
cells = boundary(cells)

centre = cells[1:-1]
left   = cells[0:-2]
right  = cells[2:]
#add your logic here...
print (np.logical_not(left) & centre & right)
```

Comment: I combined both suggestions from @abarnet and Eelco to a working solution. Don't know if I hould post it as a solution or just edit my post?

Comment: @Tengis: Post it as an answer. (I think you can also unaccept my answer and accept your own.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on **Eelco Hoogendoorn**'s comment regarding the performance of views and **abarnet**'s great logical hint here the solution that works for me:

```
def update_parallel(cells):
    cells = boundary(cells)
    center = cells[1:-1]
    left = cells[0:-2]
    right = cells[2:]
    ones = (center == 1)
    zeros = (center == 0)
    result = np.copy(center)
    result[zeros] = left[zeros]
    result[ones] = right[ones]
    num_moves = sum(np.logical_xor(center, result)) / 2   # number of moves per step
    return result, num_moves
```