# Performance analysis: Solution with and without for-loops

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I solved the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239173/numpy-vectorize-a-parallel-update) with two different solutions and wanted to know which one is faster: Using numpy-logics with a minimum of explicit loops or working iteratively by iterating over the elements of the arrays.

**Solution 1:**

```
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239173/numpy-vectorize-a-parallel-update
def function1(cells):
    assert isinstance(cells, np.ndarray)
    cells = boundary(cells)
    center = cells[1:-1]
    left = cells[0:-2]
    right = cells[2:]
    ones = (center == 1)
    zeros = (center == 0)
    result = np.copy(center)
    result[zeros] = left[zeros]
    result[ones] = right[ones]

    nmoves = sum(np.logical_xor(center, result)) / 2                                                                     
    return result, nmoves
```

**Solution 2:**

```
def function2(actual_cells):

    neighbors = np.roll(actual_cells, -1)
    assert isinstance(actual_cells, np.ndarray)
    dim = len(actual_cells)
    num_move = 0
    tmp_cells = np.zeros(dim)
    for i, j in enumerate(actual_cells):
        if j and not neighbors[i]:
            tmp_cells[i], tmp_cells[(i + 1) % dim] = 0, 1
            num_move += 1
        elif j:
            tmp_cells[i] = 1
    return tmp_cells, num_move
```

Both solutions compute the new state of my array (0s and 1s) based on the following rules:

1. if the neighbor to the right is occupied --> do not move.
2. if the neighbor to the right is empty --> move.
3. closed boundary conditions.

Anyway, when I performed a profiling over these solutions I found the following result:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

File: asep.py
Function: asep_parallel at line 113
Total time: 0.488103 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   113                                           @profile
   114                                           def function1(cells):
   120       100          113      1.1      0.0      assert isinstance(cells, np.ndarray)
   121       100         1015     10.2      0.2      cells = boundary(cells)
   122       100          120      1.2      0.0      center = cells[1:-1]
   123       100           81      0.8      0.0      left = cells[0:-2]
   124       100           79      0.8      0.0      right = cells[2:]
   125       100          537      5.4      0.1      ones = (center == 1)
   126       100          401      4.0      0.1      zeros = (center == 0)
   127       100          524      5.2      0.1      result = np.copy(center)
   128       100          813      8.1      0.2      result[zeros] = left[zeros]
   129       100         1303     13.0      0.3      result[ones] = right[ones]
   130       100       482996   4830.0     99.0      nmoves = sum(np.logical_xor(center, result)) / 2
   131       100          121      1.2      0.0      return result, nmoves


Timer unit: 1e-06 s
```

and

```
File: asep.py
Function: asep_parallel at line 133
Total time: 0.790097 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   133                                           @profile
   134                                           def asep_parallel(actual_cells):
   143       100         2399     24.0      0.3      neighbors = np.roll(actual_cells, -1)
   144       100          132      1.3      0.0      assert isinstance(actual_cells, np.ndarray)
   145       100           79      0.8      0.0      dim = len(actual_cells)
   146       100           56      0.6      0.0      num_move = 0
   147       100          317      3.2      0.0      tmp_cells = np.zeros(dim)
   148    250100       204902      0.8     25.9      for i, j in enumerate(actual_cells):
   149    250000       219355      0.9     27.8          if j and not neighbors[i]:
   150     10000        10698      1.1      1.4              tmp_cells[i], tmp_cells[(i + 1) % dim] = 0, 1
   151     10000         7014      0.7      0.9              num_move += 1
   152    240000       164852      0.7     20.9          elif j:
   153    230000       180211      0.8     22.8              tmp_cells[i] = 1
   154       100           82      0.8      0.0      return tmp_cells, num_move
```

99% of the time of the first solution goes in the line counting the number of moves! What the hell?

I replace the line counting the number of moves with

`sum(right[ones] == 0 )` 
which was **only** slightly better (93.8%).

Any ideas how to get ride of that monster line?

**EDIT**:

replacing `sum` by `np.sum` helps indeed.

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

File: asep_fast.py
Function: asep_parallel at line 113
Total time: 0.358175 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   113                                           @profile
   114                                           def asep_parallel(cells):
   115                                               """
   116                                               update of cells
   117                                               :parameter: actual state of cells
   118                                               :rtype : cells with new state and number of moves
   119                                               """
   120     10000         9947      1.0      2.8      assert isinstance(cells, np.ndarray)
   121     10000        70264      7.0     19.6      cells = boundary(cells)
   122     10000        10755      1.1      3.0      center = cells[1:-1]
   123     10000         7404      0.7      2.1      left = cells[0:-2]
   124     10000         7056      0.7      2.0      right = cells[2:]
   125     10000        29433      2.9      8.2      ones = (center == 1)
   126     10000        22100      2.2      6.2      zeros = (center == 0)
   17     10000        32578      3.3      9.1      result = np.copy(center)
   128     10000        31545      3.2      8.8      result[zeros] = left[zeros]
   129     10000        24829      2.5      6.9      result[ones] = right[ones]
   130     10000       103271     10.3     28.8      nmoves = np.sum(np.logical_xor(center, result)) / 2
   131     10000         8993      0.9      2.5      return result, nmoves
```

Comment: What happens if you use numpy's `np.sum` instead of the python built-in?